# Data not passed from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-ajax

i have one webapi app in which i have one code to populate a table in the view

the controller(Home) code is

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        var com = new TrainingDBEntities();
        var records = from emp in com.tblEmployees
                      select new Employee
                      {
                          empID  = emp.empID,
                          empName = emp.empName,
                          skill=emp.skill,

                      };
        return records.ToList();
    }
```

and in view

```
//show emp details
        $('#btshw').click(function () {


            $.ajax({


                url: "/Home/GetEmployees",

                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        var Row = "<tr><td>";
                        Row += result[i].empID + "</td><td>";
                        Row += result[i].empName + "</td><td>";
                        Row += result[i].skill + "</td><td>";
                        $('#emplist').append(Row);

                    }
                    $('#emplist').append("</table>");
                }
                ,
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err.status.Text);

                }
            });
        });
```

but after execution i got a table having 3 columns and all having values 'undefined' , i have debug the code and  in the onclick event its going to the controller and it returns the correct value but data is not correct when reaching in the view(in ajax code)

Comment: Why don't you use JsonResult?

Comment: i am new to mvc so whether jsonresult is good for this ?? if yes please show one sample code here

Comment: @SirwanAfifi  : thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the result type to [JsonResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetEmployees()
{
      var com = new TrainingDBEntities();
      var records = from emp in com.tblEmployees
                          select new Employee
                          {
                              empID = emp.empID,
                              empName = emp.empName,
                              skill = emp.skill,

                          };
       return Json(records.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Comment: ya i used json and i edit the code in the view for accessing the json data